# Absolute positioning of images in Html NewsLetter

Tags: html, css, absolute, newsletter

I have a main image for my html News letter, I am trying to position 5 images(image buttons) on top of my main image in certain positions. If I position them with absolute it renders fine when displaying in an web browser, as soon as I embed the html page in an email (outlook) the images get thrown to the side.

What is best method to accomplish this when it comes to html News Letters.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user1475479 You can use [VML](http://emailbg.net/) to create a background image and then put your image buttons on top using a standard table layout like the example I have below.

Another option is to use one big image and use [image maps](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp), but this is bad practice in email as many subscribers don't turn on images, and in this case, your email would be blank and they wouldn't see your buttons.

The best and most common solution would be to just break up your large image into smaller ones, and lay it out in a table. That way for each image you can assign an alt tag, so if the subscriber doesn't load the images, it still holds its structure, and people still know what is what and where to click. Note - It is very important to add display:block; to your images any time they are alone in a table cell.

@lukeocom - a few issues with your example, instead of editing your response, I rebuilt it below. Your images all need to have `style="display:block;"` and it is probably better to set widths and heights in pixels. Also, you need to declare all colors as 6 digit hex codes, and in html declarations you don't need to include px (just needed in css).

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#959595">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" width="600" bgcolor="#757575">
        <a href=""><img src="yourHeader.png" alt="Header" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" height="100"  width="600"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="50" style="vertical-align: top;background-color:#555555;">
        <a href=""><img src="sideBars.png" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" alt="" height="200" width="50"></a>
    </td>
    <td width="500" valign="top" style="padding:20px;">
      <font style="font-family: Century Gothic, Avant Garde, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;">
        PUT YOUR CONTENT HERE
      </font>
    </td>
    <td width="50" style="vertical-align: top;background-color:#555555;">
        <a href=""><img src="sideBars.png" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" alt="" height="200" width="50"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <a href=""><img src="yourFooter.png" alt="Footer" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" height="100" width="600"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

If you want the whole thing to center float, wrap it in this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title>
  <style type="text/css">           
    /* Client-specific Styles */
    #outlook a {padding:0;}
    body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;} /* force default font sizes */
    .ExternalClass {width:100%;} .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Hotmail */
    #backgroundTable {margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; line-height: 100% !important;}
    table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
  </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table bgcolor="#252525" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td><table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td valign="top" style="padding:30px;">

PUT THE ABOVE TABLE IN HERE

</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></body></html>
```

I use html strict instead of xhtml, but works the same minus the self closing img tags.

Comment: VML is only for pattern images, am I wrong? What about a landscape image and a caption text over it?

Comment: @Tilt It depends on the size of your image. If you make it as big as your table cell, there is no repeating. But yes, it is a tiled image.

Answer (score 0):

Ive just spent the past week on one email, such a pain! I have found the best approach for html emails is to use a table layout. There are plenty of tags that just dont work for email. And there are plenty of things that render differently per email client. Outlook is my most hated!

If the images you are using dont have any links on them, then use photoshop to create header and footer banners, then use your table layout to display them. Use inline style too as sometimes id or class names arent supported. Its better to be safe...

an example table layout by row would be:

```
|header image|
|side bar image(optional) | content (can use another table here) | side bar image|(optional)
|footer image|
```

heres a temp..

```
<table style="font-size:10pt;background-color: #fff; width:600px;max-width:600px;overflow:hidden; margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px;border-collapse:collapse;border:0;">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" width="600px">
            <img src="yourHeader.png" alt="" style="vertical-align:bottom;" height="100%"
            width="100%" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50px" style="vertical-align: top;background-color:#fff;">
            <img src="sideBars.png" alt="" height="100%" width="100%" />
        </td>
        <td width="500px" style="background-color:#fff;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;">PUT YOUR CONTENT HERE</td>
        <td width="50px" style="vertical-align: top;background-color:#333399;">
            <img src="sideBars.png" alt="right image" height="100%" width="100%" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="yourFooter.png" alt="Bottom banner image" style="vertical-align:top;"
            height="100%" width="100%" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Some further reading...

Outlook css and tag support - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx

General html email tips - http://www.verticalresponse.com/sites/www.verticalresponse.com/files/html_tips_for_email_guide.pdf

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks for the reply @lukeocom , Unfortunately the image buttons do have links. how would this accomplished it seems crazy to not have that support, surely there must be some way to do this??

Comment: you could try using an image map, I think that is supported. You basically have to pretend you're back in 1998 and develop for that as almost all useful css rules aren't supported, such as position: or background-image:. But again, the best approach is to try using tables. Put each image in a cell, and just use solid background colours.. If you find an easier way Id be glad to hear it.

Comment: @user1475479 see answer above regarding re: image links